# Creating RSS Feed using rows containing HTML cause Feed to be blank

Tags: php, mysql, html, rss

Sorry if this has been asked before - there's a question with a similar title but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

What I am doing is fetching results from a DB and printing them out inside the appropriate tags to create an RSS Feed.

The only problem is the body of the article contains html tags so my rss feed doesn't load correctly.

So far I have tried:

```
$rssfeed .= '<description>' . htmlentities($row['text') . '</description>';
```

and

```
$rssfeed .= '<description>' . htmlspecialchars($row['text'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '</description>';
```

Using either of those just gives me a completely blank feed.

I actually just tried this aswell and got the same result:

```
$rssfeed .= '<description>' . $row['text']. '</description>';
```

I'm more confused now as surely that should have worked? The only thing I can think of is that the row in the database is too long for the RSS Feed as it's a full article worth of text and HTML in there.

I wasn't sure if it would automatically be truncated or not.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This is some sample output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>RSS feed</title>
            <link>http://www.12345.co.uk</link>
            <description>RSS Feed from 12345.co.uk</description>
            <language>en-uk</language>
            <copyright>Copyright (C) 2011 12345.co.uk</copyright>
            <item>
                <title>Wear safe but stylish sunglasses on the slopes</title>
                <description><![CDATA["<p>Holidaymakers hitting the slopes this year must remember to pack a pair of sunglasses alongside their skis, one expert has highlighted.</p>
                <p>Dharmesh Patel, chairman of the Eyecare Trust, noted that UV protective eyewear is a must for skiers.</p>
                <p>Posted by xxxxx</p>v"]]>
                </description>
                <link></link>
                <pubDate>Mon, 03 Oct 2011 16:57:09 +0000</pubDate>
            </item>
```

Comment: You don't close either the `<channel>` nor the `<rss>`-tag.

Comment: I must have deleted it by mistake once I copied it - the article was huge so I only kept a couple of lines - I am definitely closing them in my PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since RSS is an XML-Language, you'll want to use an  CDATA section:

```
<description><![CDATA["<b>Use tags here</b>"]]></description>
```

In PHP, you can easily archive this (with the [`XMLWriter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php)) by using the [`startCData()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-start-cdata.php) and [`endCData()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-end-cdata.php)-methods.

If the XML-Reader displays your HTML correctly depends on the parser it's using. Using escape-sequences is however [valid XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#dt-cdsection).

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work - any more ideas as I think this is probably the issue. `$rssfeed .= '<description>' . <![CDATA["$row['text']"]]> . '</description>';`

Comment: It should be `$rssfeed .= '<description><![CDATA["' .$row['text']. 'v"]]></description>';` Also, you shouldn't simply echo out the whole XML-Structure, but use (for example) `XMLWriter` to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I get the RSS bit at the top of the page in Firefox but the feed itself is blank. Really have no idea what's wrong :(

Comment: that should be th sample xml output up now

Comment: Have you set the content-type to `text/xml` using PHPs [`header()`-function?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I used `header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");`. The feed will work fine if I use another database row that is plain text for the description so it's just this row that is causing problems - i.e. it contains HTML and the data in each is pretty large aswell so I'm not sure if that's an issue or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5092/discussion-between-lukas-knuth-and-martincarlin87)

Answer (score 1):

try strip_tags($row['text']);
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

update (i have all ok):

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>RSS feed</title>
        <link>http://www.12345.co.uk</link>
        <description>RSS Feed from 12345.co.uk</description>
        <language>en-uk</language>
        <copyright>Copyright (C) 2011 12345.co.uk</copyright>
        <item>
            <title>Wear safe but stylish sunglasses on the slopes</title>
            <description><![CDATA["<p>Holidaymakers hitting the slopes this year must remember to pack a pair of sunglasses alongside their skis, one expert has highlighted.</p>
            <p>Dharmesh Patel, chairman of the Eyecare Trust, noted that UV protective eyewear is a must for skiers.</p>
            <p>Posted by xxxxx</p>v"]]>
            </description>
            <link></link>
            <pubDate>Mon, 03 Oct 2011 16:57:09 +0000</pubDate>
        </item>
```

i dont know why but it want show code ending it just:  `</channel></rss>';?>`

Comment: I tried `strip_tags` but it didn't seem to work. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: i tried Your code in php file like this - see update in my comment